# How do i count two values together

Tags: jquery, scope

to start with I am pretty new to jQuery so I am sorry if this is an easy question but i could not find the answer here anywhere.

I have two values from a slider. But I can not get it done to count the two values together. Here is the code where I tried to do it:

```
<script>    
$(".slider2").slider({
    change: function(event, ui) {
      var prodPrijs = $("#dom_element").text(ui.value);
    }
  });
  $(".slider").slider({
    change: function(event, ui) {
      $("#dom_element2").text(ui.value);
      var bierPrijs = ui.value;
    }
  });

</script>

<script>
    $(".slider2").slider({
    change: function(event, ui) {
      var prodPrijs = $("#dom_element").text(ui.value);

      console.log(prodPrijs + bierPrijs);
    }
  });
</script>
```

And here are the sliders for extra information:

```
<script>
   $(function () {
    $(".slider").slider({
        range: "max",
        value: 0.00,
        min: 0.00,
        step: 0.01,
        max: 5.00, 
        create: function () {
            $(this).slider( "option", "value", $(this).next().val() );
        },
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            // ID van slider pakken
            var id = $(this).attr("id");
            //Waarde weergeven van slider
            $("span[class*=" + id + "]").text(ui.value);
            $("input[class*=" + id + "]").val(ui.value);
            var x = ui.value;
        }
    });
});
</script>

<script>
        $(function () {
         $(".slider2").slider({
             range: "max",
             value: 0,
             min: 0,
             step: 1,
             max: 1000,
             create: function () {
                 $(this).slider( "option", "value", $(this).next().val() );
             },
             slide: function (event, ui) {
                 // ID van slider pakken
                 var id = $(this).attr("id");
                 //Waarde weergeven van slider
                 $("span[class*=" + id + "]").text(ui.value);
                 $("input[class*=" + id + "]").val(ui.value);
                 var z = ui.value;
             }
         });
     });
     </script>
```

Thanks for your time really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

If your issue is in this line:

```
console.log(prodPrijs + bierPrijs);
```

the problem is: the two variables have a locale scope. In order to make them visible outside, you may  define those variable global like:

```
window.prodPrijs  = ....
```

In order to sum these two strings as numbers you need to convert them to number: prefix with a plus sign:

```
console.log(+prodPrijs + +bierPrijs);
```

Because using global variable is not a good pratice, you can save the values to each slider as a data attribute:

```
$(".slider2").data('prodPrijs', ui.value);
```

and when you need to get the value you can write:

```
$(".slider2").data('prodPrijs')
```

For details see [.data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/)

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring your variables inside of blocks, and they're not visible outside of those blocks.

I'd recommend creating the variables outside of the jquery code (like as the first thing in the  tag), update the relevant variable, then show the sum of the two.